# Proof on Degenerate LP program

Tags: linear-programming, primal-simplex, degeneracy

do all degenerate LP have have an equivalent non degenerate LP?
for example the following is a degenerate LP
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&1&1&0\\0&1&0&1&0&1&0\\0&0&1&1&1&1&0\\0&0&1&0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix},\\b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
you can choose initial basis indices as `[0,1,2,any]`.and also $x\ge0$, what could be the non degenerate case? I must warn you this program isn't unbounded yet Mathematica identifies it as unbounded.

**Edit**
 With prubin's answer i have reduced the system to $$x1+x2-x3+x6=1\\x3+x6+x7=1$$ which is also degenerate assuming $x1$ and $x2$ are included in the basis on some other 2 additional rows. And also this system isn't totally unimodular due to $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you think the above problem is degenerate? I assumed the problem was in the form of $Ax=b$. With regard to the objective direction, e.g. equal to zero, the problem has an optimal solution.

Comment: @A.Omidi has at least one Basic feasible solution for which one or more basic variables go to zero. let's assume you apply the given basis you'll see this fact.

Comment: degeneracy is raised when the pivoting element would not be unique. Also, it implies there exist multiple optimal solutions on another side (dual form), and it likely comes within many of the optimization models. It would be temporary or permanent. It is permanent if, the minimum ratio test does not change in the consequence iterations of the simplex tableau, and also is equal to zero.

Comment: It is already possible a basic variable would be degenerate which means it can have more than one tableau that at least one associated is optimal. Would you say, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Did this constraint system arise by inserting slack variables into inequality constraints? If so, it might be easier to answer based on the original constraint set. Also, just to check, are you requiring all variables to be nonnegative?

Comment: @A.Omidi The system is degenerate starting from the basis given. you realize that the solution given by the basis isn't unique. note that you can append `any` other column and still have the solution.

Comment: @prubin This system has no slack variables as we already know the starting basis.

Comment: Are you assuming that all variables are nonnegative? (This is not stated above.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First comment: LPs are not degenerate; corner points of their feasible regions (equivalently, basic feasible solutions) can be degenerate. As stated in Henrik's answer, degeneracy occurs when more than $n$ of the defining hyperplanes (including those corresponding to bounds on the variables) are binding at a corner, where $n$ is the number of variables. Here $n=7$ and at $x=(1,1,1,0,0,0,0)$ we have 8 binding hyperplanes (four from the equation constraints, four from the nonnegativity of variables $x_4,\dots,x_7.$ Note that I'm assuming that all seven variables are required to be nonnegative, even though it is not stated in the problem.

Suppose we use the four equations to solve for four variables in terms of the other three, as follows:
$$x_1 = 1 - x_5 - x_6$$
$$x_2 = 1 - x_4 - x_6$$
$$x_3 = 1 - x_4 - x_5 - x_6$$
$$x_4 = 1 - x_3 - x_6 = x_4 + x_5.$$
Using that, we can express the feasible region in terms of $x_5,\dots,x_7$, with the nonnegativity of $x_1,\dots,x_4$ translating into the following constraints:
$$x_5 + x_6 \le 1$$
$$ x_4 + x_6 \le 1$$
$$x_4 + x_5 + x_6\le 1$$
$$x_4 + x_5 \ge 0.$$
At $(x_4,x_5,x_6) = (0,0,0)$ we have three nonnegative constraints plus the fourth inequality binding, so the corner is degenerate. Note, though, that the fourth inequality is redundant (implied by nonnegativity of $x_4$ and $x_5$), so we can drop it and get an equivalent problem (same feasible region) where the corner is no longer degenerate.

So there is an equivalent formulation where the corner is nondegenerate, but it is not obvious from the original formulation. In particular, just dropping any one of the four equation constraints or any one of the nonnegativity requirements in the original model changes the feasible region.

Comment: about the equivalent formulation, i also have only equality constraints, does that mean i can get the equivalent formulation by simply replacing variables until i couldn't. to be honest i never thought of that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Yes, I used your equation constraints to solve for some variables in terms of the others, as stated in my answer.

Comment: I mean you gave me an alien perspective on the problem though not directly. and i am thankful.

Comment: You're welcome. But drat, now I'm unmasked as an alien!

Answer (score 4):

This is a really interesting question that I don't think is completely understood yet.

One research paper you may want to look into is [Im, Jiyoung, and Henry Wolkowicz. “Strict Feasibility and Degeneracy in Linear Programming,” 2022, 1–20](http://arxiv.org/abs/2203.02795) who make the following definition:

> For a general polyhedron $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, a point $p \in P$ is called a basic solution if there are $n$ linearly independent active constraints at $p$. In addition, if there are more than $n$ active constraints at the point $p \subseteq P$, then the point $p$ is called degenerate.

*Note: With respect to the primal problem, $Ax=b \in \mathbb{R}^m, x \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$, we have $m$ active constraints from the equality system (by feasibility), $n-m$ active constraints from bounds of $x_\mathcal{N}$ (in basic solutions), and degeneracy holds if any bounds of $x_\mathcal{B}$ are active.*

The authors then go on to show that the absence of strict feasibility implies that all basic solutions are degenerate, and point to facial reduction as a method to obtain strict feasibility via a series of reformulations which ultimately reduce the degree of degeneracy.

Note, however, that the above method is not capable of removing all types of degeneracy and to further your understanding it may be beneficial to look at the classic assignment problem:

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\textrm{minimize}   & \sum_{i=1}^T \sum_{j=1}^T c_{ij} x_{ij} \\
\textrm{subject to} & \sum_{i=1}^T x_{ij} = 1,&\text{for all $j=1,\ldots,T$},\\
 & \sum_{j=1}^T x_{ij} = 1, &\text{for all $i=1,\ldots,T$},\\
& 0 \leq x_{ij} \leq 1, &\text{for all $i=1,\ldots,T$, $j=1,\ldots,T$}.
\end{array}
$$

This formulation is totally unimodular causing all basic solutions to be integer feasible, $x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$, with exactly $T$ variables equal to 1. Since $x_\mathcal{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{2T}$, this means that all basic solutions are degenerate. Trying to reformulate it you find that one constraint is redundant and can be thrown away (tonnes of degeneracy remains however). Furthermore, facial reduction is not applicable because strict feasibility is satisfied (just let $x_{ij} = 1/T$ for all $i=1,\ldots,T$, $j=1,\ldots,T$ to see this).

It is not at all obvious if there exists a formulation of the assignment problem that is nondegenerate, and it should serve well to test any ideas that comes up. What you can always do, however, at least in theory, is to randomly perturb all bounds by the tiniest amounts to obtain a nondegenerate problem whose optimal basis is also an optimal basis in the unperturbed problem with probability 1. This is one of the main motivations for using perturbation strategies in simplex implementations. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I get your Idea about perturbation, but there is a problem when i want to mantain the structure of basic matrix throughout the optimization process, it is lower diagonally dominant matrix with each diagonal block matrix being 4x4 if i alter the structure for a very large problem (over billions of variables no slack variables) i take an entire month finding an optimal solution. Also the diagonal block matrices must at optimal have a definite path of changes encountered. raw perturbation is not an option for me, but thanks.

Comment: Hi @someonerandom, welcome to stackexchange. Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so we encourage you to use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post. In this case your title was "Proof on Degenerate LP program" and main question "do all degenerate LP have have an equivalent non degenerate LP?" suggestion you are looking for theory. If this is not the case, for please edit your question or create a new one to reflect your practical need. More information on https://stackexchange.com/tour.